# JQuery UI Drupal 6 causing TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal-6

I'm using excellent JQuery upload widget on Drupal 6. Since there is no designated module for that widget (there is for D7, but not D6) I'm adding the necessary files using `drupal_add_js` (via a helper module).

So the file upload works, but if I add the date pop up to a Drupal form, it causes the JQuery UI (activated by the date pop up) to break.

To be more specific it produces this error message:

```
"TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function"
```

I've read some threads dealing with similar issues and tried to follow some of the suggestions given. As far as I can tell the problem is this:

1. The JQuery file upload widget uses the `jquery.ui.widget.js` called from the `/fileupload/js/` folder (using `drupal_add_js` in a helper module)
2. If I add a date pop up field to a Drupal form the Jquery UI from `sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/ui.core.js` kicks in, which already contains `jquery.ui.widget` causing the error

Now at this point I thought it would just make sense to remove my call to `jquery.ui.widget.js` but the problem is that:

1. Other `fileupload.js` depend on it, and:
2. The D6 Jquery UI module adds `/sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/ui.core.js` AFTER all files included via `drupal_add_js`, and as a result breaking `fileupload` as it lacks the `jquery.ui.widget` support at the time it’s read (and producing the following errors:

   ```
   TypeError: $.widget is not a function
   TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function )
   ```

I tried setting the weight of my custom module (by editing the system table in the database) to a high value but still, the Jquery UI files are added AFTER all `drupal_add_js` files.

If anyone out there could provide some further insight on how to approach this issue that would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same problem in WordPress and it turned out that the plugin using .fileupload() was adding its own version of the Jquery UI and WordPress was adding another. When I removed the additional JqueryUI it worked.

This question led me in the right direction: [jQuery UI TypeError: e.widget.extend is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631325/jquery-ui-typeerror-e-widget-extend-is-not-a-function)