# JQuery time picker add-on error

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I use jquery-ui-timepicker-addon on my page and I get this error:

> TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function on this.options =
>   $.widget.extend( {}, jquery-ui.js (line 579, col 17)

I create the control using:

```
$("input.dateInfo").datetimepicker()
```

and here I don't get any error. The error appears when I click the control (the input field). Instead of showing the datetime picker, I got the error above.

Any explanation for this error? 
I use require.js to load the javascript libraries. I have more js files that load. If is any conflict, with some other jquery plugin, how do I know where is the conflict?

**Later edit:**

I load the libraries using require.js

```
paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery/jquery.min',
        jquery_ui: 'jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui',
        jquery_ui_widget: 'jquery-picklist/jquery.ui.widget',
        jquery_ui_timepicker: 'jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap-3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min',
        bootbox:'bootstrap-3.0.0/plugins/bootbox.min',
        moment: 'moment/moment',
        //bootstrap_dateTime_picker: "bootstrap-dateTimePicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker",
        sugar: 'sugar/sugar-1.3.6.min'
    // some more lines here
    }
```

and

```
shim: {
        "jquery": ["sugar"],
        "slim_scroll": ["jquery"],
        "jquery_ui": ["jquery"],
        "jquery_ui_widget": ["jquery","jquery_ui"],
        "jquery_ui_timepicker": ["jquery", "jquery_ui"],

        "bootstrap": ["jquery_ui"],
        "less": ["jquery"],
        "sugar_loaded": ["jquery","sugar"]
        // some more lines here
    }
```

Comment: Did you load jquery before loading datetimepicker?

Comment: Yes, I did! $("input.dateInfo") returns a valid node!

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. That would still work if you loaded jquery AFTER loading datetimepicker.

Comment: jquery is load before. jquery-ui too. My guess is that is a conflict with another plug-in, and I don;t know how to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding and removing from the list of external js files I found that the conflict was with: **jquery_ui_widget: 'jquery-picklist/jquery.ui.widget'**. I removed this js file (I was luck that was a component that was no longer in use) and everything start working normally!

Thanks anyone for trying to help me. I think that this is a issue specific to my particular project that uses about 20 external js libraries, and one of them caused the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [jquery-ui-typeerror-e-widget-extend-is-not-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631325/jquery-ui-typeerror-e-widget-extend-is-not-a-function)

Check your sequence of script loading.

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js">
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js">
<script src="/scripts/other-widgets.js">
```

**EDIT:**

In your edit you mentioned that your are using require.js. With require.js you need to mention dependencies of modules to manage the load sequence else every script will be loaded asynchronously.

Now, the problem zeros down to, that one of your script depends on jquery_ui_widget but you missed to mention it as dependency:

```
shim: {
    "jquery": ["sugar"],
    "slim_scroll": ["jquery"],
    "jquery_ui": ["jquery"],
    "jquery_ui_widget": ["jquery","jquery_ui"],
    "jquery_ui_timepicker": ["jquery", "jquery_ui"],

    "bootstrap": ["jquery_ui"],
    "less": ["jquery"],
    "sugar_loaded": ["jquery","sugar"]
    // some more lines here
}
```

Here, I am about which script depends on **`jquery_ui_widget`** but my guess would be `slim_scroll` or `jquery_ui_timepicker` or `bootstrap`.

Comment: I use require.js to load the scripts.

Comment: @Zelter Ady: After the reordering, is it loading correctly now?

Comment: As I told you, my project uses require.js to load js code. I edited the question and added the require code that I use to load all my js files. Do you see something wrong there? Did I miss something?

Comment: One of your modules depend on jquery_ui_widget, and you have not mentioned it as your dependency in your shim config.
Not sure, but could it be:
`"jquery_ui_timepicker": ["jquery_ui_widget"],` or `"slim_scroll": ["jquery_ui_widget"],`